# Callback for Active Storage file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

Is there a callback for active storage files on a model

`after_update` or `after_save` is getting called when a field on the model is changed. However when you update (or rather upload a new file) no callback seems to be called?

context:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  #name :string
  has_one_attached :id_document

  after_update :call_some_service

  def call_some_service
    #do something
  end
end
```

When a new `id_document` is uploaded `after_update` is not called however when the `name` of the person is changed the `after_update` callback is executed

Comment: Have you tried `:before_save` callback?

Comment: @MasaSakano, yes, there is no action that fires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from @Uleb got me 90% of the way, but for completion sake I will post my final solution.

The issue I had was that I was not able to monkey patch the class (not sure why, even requiring the class as per @user10692737 did not help)

So I copied the source code (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc5dd0b85189811062c85520fd70de8389b55aeb/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/attachment.rb#L20)

and modified it to include the callback

```
require "active_support/core_ext/module/delegation"

# Attachments associate records with blobs. Usually that's a one record-many blobs relationship,
# but it is possible to associate many different records with the same blob. If you're doing that,
# you'll want to declare with <tt>has_one/many_attached :thingy, dependent: false</tt>, so that destroying
# any one record won't destroy the blob as well. (Then you'll need to do your own garbage collecting, though).
class ActiveStorage::Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "active_storage_attachments"

  belongs_to :record, polymorphic: true, touch: true
  belongs_to :blob, class_name: "ActiveStorage::Blob"

  delegate_missing_to :blob

  #CUSTOMIZED AT THE END:
  after_create_commit :analyze_blob_later, :identify_blob, :do_something

  # Synchronously purges the blob (deletes it from the configured service) and destroys the attachment.
  def purge
    blob.purge
    destroy
  end

  # Destroys the attachment and asynchronously purges the blob (deletes it from the configured service).
  def purge_later
    blob.purge_later
    destroy
  end


  private
    def identify_blob
      blob.identify
    end

    def analyze_blob_later
      blob.analyze_later unless blob.analyzed?
    end

    #CUSTOMIZED:
    def do_something

    end
end
```

Not sure its the best method, and will update if I find a better solution

Comment: This a bit dirty I assume, I went with adding an  `after_create_commit` on my custom object that schedules job for later with the custom analyzer. The job returns early if the attachment has not been identified/analyzed yet and gets retried over time.

Answer (score 4):

For now, it seems like there is no callback for this case.

What you could do is create a model to handle the creation of an active storage attachment which is what is created when you attach a file to your person model.

So create a new model

```
class ActiveStorageAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :after_update

  private
  def after_update
    if record_type == 'Person'
      record.do_something
    end
  end
end
```

You normally have created the model table already in your database so no need for a migration, just create this model

Comment: Let me suggest an improvement:

`record.after_attachment_update if record.respond_to? :after_attachment_update`

In this way the callback can be implemented in the record class

Comment: @uelb, thanks for this! Just watch out there are a few typos: 

`ActiveStorageAttachment => ActiveStorage::Attachment` 

`after_update: after_update => after_update :after_update`

I cannot however monkey patch the class, I have to copy over the entire class and then add to it, not sure if I'm missing something?

Entire class:
 (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc5dd0b85189811062c85520fd70de8389b55aeb/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/attachment.rb#L20)

Comment: @mdesantis where are using this code? in model call back or what?

Answer (score 3):

In my case tracking attachment timestamp worked

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :id_document

  after_save do    
    if id_document.attached? && (Time.now  - id_document.attachment.created_at)<5
      Rails.logger.info "id_document change detected"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Erm i would just comment but since this is not possible without rep..

Uelb's answer works but you need to fix the error in comments and add it as an initializer instead of model. Eg:

```
require 'active_storage/attachment'

class ActiveStorage::Attachment
  before_save :do_something

  def do_something
    puts 'yeah!'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

None of these really hit the nail on the head, but you can achieve what you were looking for by following this blog post https://redgreen.no/2021/01/25/active-storage-callbacks.html

I was able to modify the code there to work on attachments instead of blobs like this

```
Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
  module ActiveStorage::Attachment::Callbacks
    # Gives us some convenient shortcuts, like `prepended`
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    # When prepended into a class, define our callback
    prepended do
      after_commit :attachment_changed, on: %i[create update]
    end

    # callback method
    def attachment_changed
      record.after_attachment_update(self) if record.respond_to? :after_attachment_update
    end
  end

  # After defining the module, call on ActiveStorage::Blob to prepend it in.
  ActiveStorage::Attachment.prepend ActiveStorage::Attachment::Callbacks
end
```

Comment: If anyone was thinking of using this method to also do something after destroy, it's not possible since the `purge` method uses `delete` as can be seen on its [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8015c2c2cf5c8718449677570f372ceb01318a32/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/attachment.rb#L33).

Answer (score 1):

What I do is add a callback on my record:

```rb
after_touch :check_after_touch_data
```

This gets called if an ActiveStorage object is added, edited or deleted. I use this callback to check if something changed.

Answer (score 0):

you have access to "attachment_changes['name of your column'] in rails 7

So to check if a change happened to a logo, i use as an

```
after_commit: saved_change_to_logo_attached?

def saved_change_to_logo_attached?
   attachment_changes['submitted_file'].present?
end
```