# How to check if attachment is new in Rails' ActiveStorage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

In my Rails 5.2.2 app I am using Active Storage to attach `logos` to `profiles`:

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord

  has_many_attached :logos

end
```

How can I test if a **new** logo has been attached to the profile on update?

Right now, I am checking for a `logos` parameter in my controller which works fine:

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController

  def update
    if params[:profile][:logos].present?
      @profile.logo_active = true # This is the important attribute I need to set
    end
    if @profile.update(profile_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
      redirect_to profile_path
    end
  end

end
```

Is there a way to do the same in the **model**, i.e. check if an attachment is actually new and then set the `logo_active` attribute depending on that?

I toyed around with Rails' `new_record?` method but to no avail.

Comment: have you found a way around this? Experiencing this today.

Answer (score 5):

You can check if there is an attachment with

```
@profile.logos.attached?
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/Many.html#method-i-attached-3F

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing a small service that will update a Profile for you and handle logos changing. E.g. something like this:

```
# app/services/profile_updater.rb

class ProfileUpdater
  def self.call(params)
    profile = Profile.find(params.delete(:id))
    logos_was = profile.logos
    profile.assign_attributes(params)
    profile.logo_active = profile.logos != logos_was
    profile.save
  end
end
```

If you prefer callbacks over services you could play with creating callbacks for ActiveStorage models as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226228/callback-for-active-storage-file-upload)